# Polygon-filled maps not styling as specified

Tags: maps, google-fusion-tables

I've created 3 maps, based on 3 separate columns, using the default polygon-fill. Within Fusion I then changed the style on each map (using the same colour scheme for each). When first viewed each map displays correctly but when I switch to another map and then back again, the original map is no longer based on the correct column. It's as if the 3 maps are being treated as duplicates. (I did not create each one using the duplicate choice on the map drop-down menu). Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you provide more information? (Perhaps links that exhibit the problem or pictures of what you mean)

Answer (score 0):

We have a pesky bug causing this that occasionally surfaces. You can verify what's happening from the publish dialog: Publish > Get HTML and JavaScript, then look for styleId. In certain cases the same style and template IDs are getting saved for all map tabs.

A possible workaround is to remove all of your maps, then add them back one at a time. That has helped in some cases. We're working on a fix, and sorry for the inconvenience!